# Does the length of a data type depend on the architecture on the computer or on the compiler you are using?

Tags: c, types

I have read several times before that the length of the data type in C depends on the architecture on the PC.

But recently I have read documentation of a compiler and this documentation specifies the data types that you can access and the length of this data type.

So my question is, the data type length depends on the compiler your using, the architecture of the computer or both?

Comment: The length of a data type length depends on both the compiler, the architecture of the computer, and often has to pander to the operating system's ABI.  (The OS's ABI usually - but not always - accommodates the computer's architecture.)

Comment: Both.  Data types are implementation dependent.

Comment: Both. For example, on 64-bit processors an `int` could be 64-bits, but some compilers use a 32-bit `int`, because it saves memory and improves performance.

Comment: The length of the data types is decided by the implementers of the compiler. However, these decisions are often influenced by the architecture.

Comment: pointers of any data type will match the size of the addressing type (32 or 64 bit). The pointer will be either 4 or 8 bytes correspondingly.

Comment: It is set by the compiler you are using. The decision of the compiler implementors is affected by the architecture of the computer it is targeting. While it is uncommon, I have even used a compiler that allowed configuration of data type sizes. (Unfortunately, this didn't extend to making the startup code and libraries entirely consistent with your choices.)

Comment: You can also specify data length using char( 1 byte), short(2), long(4), double(8), float(4). This type are independent and always the same size.

Comment: @PtitXav: Those types are not always the same size, nor are they fully independent. The C standard specifies a `char` is always one “byte,” because a “byte” is the unit of measurement for the size of types and `char` is set by the standard to be one byte, but it can be more than eight bits. A `short` must be at least 16 bits, but it can be one byte if a byte is 16 bits or more, and it can be more than 16 bits. Similarly, `long`, `float`, and `double` can vary.

Answer (score 5):

The final determination of the size of each type is up to the C implementation, subject to the constraints of the C standard. (The standard specifies things such as that `char` is one “byte,” and a byte is eight bits or more, and that certain types are the same size as each other.)

A C implementation typically consists of a compiler, header files, libraries, a linker, and a target system to run on, and possibly other components. The compiler has a large influence on the characteristics of types, especially the core types of C, but sometimes header files complete the definitions of types, so that one compiler may be used with different sets of header files that provide different types.

Most C implementations are influenced by the characteristics of the execution architecture they are designed for. An `int` will often be the same size as a general processor register, and a pointer (of any type) will often be the smallest size that is a power-of-two number of bytes and has enough bits to span the address space of the target architecture.

However, C implementations may be designed for other purposes. I have seen a C implementation that used a 32-bit pointer size for a 64-bit architecture, for the purpose of reducing memory usage in programs that had a great many pointers. A C implementation could also be designed to run older C code on a new processor, so the C implementation used the sizes of types that the older code was written for rather than sizes that would be more “natural” on the new processor.

Comment: thank u Eric, i really aprecciate it!

Answer (score 3):

It can depend on either.  Of course the executable produced by the compiler will need to run efficiently on the CPU architecture that it is compiled for, so if (for example) you are cross-compiling software to run it on a 16-bit microcontroller, than it is very likely that `sizeof(int)==2` in the compiled code, even if you are using a modern 64-bit desktop PC to do the compilation.

Simultaneously to that, it's also up to the compiler writers (within [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)) to decide what sizes various non-width-specific data types should have in their compiler.  So for example, some compilers set `sizeof(int)==4` while others set `sizeof(int)==8`, for reasons particular to their own history and user's needs.